# What is the correct way to fetch user details from Onelogin id_token in Rest Controller

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, onelogin

I am implementing Onelogin authentication for my React Spring boot application where User authentication is happening at frontend adn two tokens `access_token` and `id_token` are received.

As user details like username,email are only available in `id_token` not in `access_token`, it's being passed to Spring boot backend for verification and expiry like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JWTWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            logger.info("In JwtSecurityConfig");
            http.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                            "/configuration/ui",
                            "/swagger-resources/**",
                            "/configuration/security",
                            "/swagger-ui.html",
                            "/swagger-ui/**",
                            "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        }

}
```

Then In filter I am fetching the username and email from the id_token that is being passed in header like this:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${jwt.http.request.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    private static final Pattern BEARER_PATTERN =
            Pattern.compile("^(?i:bearer) ([\\w\\x2b\\x2d\\x2e\\x2f\\x7e]+\\x3d*)$");


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestToken = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
        String email=null,name=null;

        if(StringUtils.hasText(requestToken)) {
            requestToken.replace("Bearer ","");
            String[] chunks = requestToken.split("\\.");
            Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getUrlDecoder();
            String payload = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[1]));
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ObjectNode object = mapper.readValue(payload, ObjectNode.class);
            email = object.get("email").asText();
            name = object.get("name").asText();

            if (email != null) {
                request.setAttribute("user",email);
                request.setAttribute("name",name);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach for verification/validation of token and then passing the user details to controller.

I have tried using `Principal` Object injected into controller but it's not having the required user details in it.

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    System.out.println(principal);
    return principal;
}
```

Please suggest if I am following the correct approach for OpenId Connect implementation with onelogin or there is better way to do it.

Regards,

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you: https://curity.io/resources/learn/oidc-spring-boot/#create-a-spring-boot-application It's about using Spring with the Curity Identity Server (a product that I'm affiliated with), but this uses OIDC, so the Spring part can be used with any OIDC solution. It shows how to get the data from an ID token into a principal.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski here redirection and user authentication is happening at backend not on the frontend layer. In my case frontend is deployed separately from backedn and redirection/auth is happening at frontend. Token validation is supposed to do at backend.